# jQuery className and removeClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass, classname

I have the following condition in a long function:

```
if ( shipSet == true ) {
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).style.background = 'gray';
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).className = 'optional';      
} else {
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).removeAttribute('style');
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).removeClass('optional');
}
```

the `style` lines work fine, whether true or false, but the `className` and `removeClass` lines aren't working. Any suggestions? Am I just not using them properly?

Comment: `$("#" + shippingFields[i]).style.` should be `$("#" + shippingFields[i])[0].style.`. You need to understand the difference between DOM element and jQuery object.

Comment: `className` is a property on the DOM element, not a jQuery function. You should be using the jquery css function instead: `$("#" + shippingFields[i]).css("background", "gray");`

Comment: even if i use `document.getElementById(shippingFields[i]).className = 'optional';` it still doesn't work. And @Satpal, `THE STYLE LINES WORK FINE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `("#" + shippingFields[i])` return a jQuery object.

You need to use [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) instead:

```
if ( shipSet == true ) {
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).css('background','gray');
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).addClass('optional');      
} else {
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).removeAttr('style');
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).removeClass('optional');
}
```

Also, you can use [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)  to set the styles of your elements.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) (to add class to element) and [`removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) (to remove class from element):

```
$("#" + shippingFields[i]).addClass('optional');      
$("#" + shippingFields[i]).removeClass('optional');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( shipSet == true ) {
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).css('background','gray');
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).addClass('optional');      
} else {
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).removeAttr('style');
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).removeClass('optional');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, for adding class name use always `$("#attributeID").addClass('ClassName');`

```
if ( shipSet == true ) {
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).css('background','gray');
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).addClass('optional');      
} else {
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).removeAttr('style');
    $("#" + shippingFields[i]).removeClass('optional');
}
```